# How to set First viewController Screen as a Default opening screen when ever open a app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

Hi I am new to iPhone development, I am developing a TabBar app it's contains **5 tabbar Items**.

When I am **close app** at **third TabBar viewController screen** and again when I am opening app that time same **third TabBar viewController** screen only opening.

How to **set App first screen**  as a default App opening Screen in iphone.

I need to set **first screen** as a default opening screen when ever open a app.

Could you please share your ideas here..

Comment: don't vote down without understanding any ones answer... my previous answer is because you wrote killing app , not close app....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are setting your application to be run in background, so whenever you close your app the app will run in background and resume on startUp.

so just do one thing 
Go to your info.plist and set value for
`Application does not run in background` to `YES`

[image: Take a look]

Answer (score 1):

When you close the app, it doesn't *KILL* it, it just suspends it. Unless you set the option to kill it when you close it.

I suggest you read [Apple Documentation For Application Flow](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)

And possibly read the other documents Apple have provided for you there if you are new to all of this.

Answer (score 1):

In your application's `Info.plist`, add a boolean key `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` with the value YES.

This will always exit the app  (instead of running in background) when you close it. On opening app again, first view controller will appear instead of where you left it last time.

Comment: tnx for your message.. I set this via App Target->Info-> add Application does not run background->YES. it's working ...

Answer (score 0):

If application is killed by default it loads all settings in Application Delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Here you can modify your root view controller, which I presume is some kind of tab bar view controller.

So there is probably some code in that method which defines which tab to load.

However if you want to show specific tab after application enters in the foreground use Application delegate method:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
```

Or

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

Comment: I set this via App Target->Info->add Application does not run background->Yes  it's working for me..Tnx for message

Answer (score 0):

When exiting the app by for example pressing the home button on the iPhone the app is not terminated. Instead the execution is suspended but the app will remain in memory until iOS decides to remove it. This means that when you enter the app again it will be in the same state you left it. You can see if the app is still in memory by doubletapping the home button.

When your app becomes active the method `applicationDidBecomeActive:` in your `UIApplicationDelegate` will be called. You can implement that method to set the state you want your app to be in when it is restored.

I would not recommend explicitly killing the app when it is suspended. That forces the app to be reloaded each time it is started which will degrade performance.

For more information see [Apple's documentation on app states](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html).